# collision not happening for same object in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

objects are not fast moving, they are very slow 6 same objects sometimes collision works sometimes not for same objects? Is it usual?
 I am using ontriggerenter everything is working but sometimes some object on hexagon not collapsing.

1 ball hitting 6 same pieces. 5 of them collapsing 1 is not collapsing every time, and its changing

their tag is same name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`OnTriggerEnter` would not allow a physics interaction from two objects. The `GameObject` with the `Collider` set to isTrigger = true would pass through the other object. From [MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerEnter(Collider)](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerEnter.html):

## Description

OnTriggerEnter is called when the GameObject collides with another GameObject.

The given other Collider has details about the trigger event, such as the name of its GameObject. Either of the two GameObjects must have a Rigidbody component. The Rigidbody component has both Rigidbody.useGravity and Rigidbody.isKinematic set to false. These prevents the GameObject from falling under gravity and having kinematic behavior. One Collider has Collider.isTrigger set to true. The GameObject with Collider.isTrigger set to true has OnTriggerEnter called when the other GameObject touches or passes through it. OnTriggerEnter occurs after FixedUpdate ends.